# how can I broadcast an object of a class from a service to an activity?

Tags: android, class, service, parcelable, parcel

I have a userObject Class(made it parcelable for following implementation) and I wrote the below code in my service. Just want to know, is there any other efficient/easy way then Android Parcelable in which I need not to make my class Parcelable?

```
  public  final static String PAR_KEY = "par_key";
userObject currentUser = new userObject(uid,uname,role,status,avatarUrl,profileUrl);
                                Intent Connect = new Intent("onChatConnect");//add action
                                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                                mBundle.putParcelable(PAR_KEY, currentUser);
                                Connect.putExtras(mBundle);
                                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(Connect);
```

Comment: Not for a broadcast.  Broadcasts don't always go to the same process, they're built to be an IPC mechanism.  That means the class needs to be serialized.  Which means a Parsable in Android.

Comment: so is there anyway other then broadcast in which I can send the events with object of a class?

Comment: Via the binder or via aidl.  But neither are pretty to use.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547577/how-can-a-remote-service-send-messages-to-a-bound-activity for an example of using a bound service and the binder.